# Unexpected behaviour of "!print("1") || 1" in php

Tags: php, operator-precedence, associativity

**Example1:**

```
if(!print("1") || 1){
   echo "a";
}else{
   echo "b";
}
```

**Output**

```
1b
```

The **Example 1** is printing "**1b**" instead of "**1a**". According to me, inside if the final condition should be **if(0 || 1)** after solving **!print("1")**.

But the **Example 2** is printing "***1a***".

**Example 2:**

```
if((!print("1")) || 1){
   echo "a";
}else{
   echo "b";
}
```

**Output**

```
1a
```

Can you elaborate, why the or condition in the first statement didn't work.

Comment: Yes but there is a not operator at first.

Comment: It must have something to do with `print` being “special”, I suppose.  `print` is not actually a function, it is a “language construct”. The manual says it always returns 1, but if you replace it with `function p () { echo "1"; return 1; }`, then both versions above give you `1a` as a result. You are not required to use parentheses with the argument list, so `print("1")` and `print "1"` are effectively the same thing. That must somehow contribute to the effect here, I suppose.

Comment: Even weirder: Replace with `print("3")` in both cases - and the first one will still get you `1b`, but the second one gets you `3a`.

Comment: So the output of !print "1" is false,but there is also an "||" condition which is true but it is not reading "||" condition.

Comment: I think this is effectively treated as `!print("1" || 1)`. `"1" || 1` is `1`, so you get that as output from the print statement - and then the return value (which is also 1, but a “different” 1), gets negated afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing here is to realise that `print` is not a function, and doesn't take arguments in parentheses - the parentheses aren't optional, they're just not part of the syntax at all.

When you write `print("1");` the print statement has a single argument, the expression `("1")`. That is if course just another way of writing `"1"` - you could add any number of parentheses and it wouldn't change the value.

So when you write `print("1") || 1` the argument to print is the expression `("1") || 1`. That expression is evaluated using PHP's type juggling rules as `true || true`  which is `true`. Then it's passed to `print` and - completely coincidentally to what you were trying to print - is type juggled to the string `"1"`.

The print statement is then treated as an expression returning true, and the `!` makes it false, so the if statement doesn't run.

This is a good reason not to use parentheses next to keywords like `print`, `require`, and `include` - they give the mistaken impression of "attaching" an argument to the keyword.