# The trick of the ternary operator?

Tags: php

Is there a way to use such a construction?

```
Auth::check() ?? echo "<h1>Log in please</h1>"
```

Auth::check checks whether the user is authorized

This trick with ternary operator would make it much easier for me to read the code

Comment: Did you try it? Thats the simple way to answer this question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, doesn't work    : (

Comment: Look at how it works [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm)

Comment: `echo` is a statement. `print()` is an expression.

Comment: @mario, ok, if i want to return something? return "text"

Comment: Same thing. The expression within the return statement however is suitable for operators and such.

Comment: Unless `Auth::check()` returns NULL when you are not logged in, this is not what you want

Comment: @mario plase, please, could you give me your thoughts via example?

Comment: @RiggsFolly return doesn't work with ternary operator

Comment: Read the comment again!! `The Null coalescing operator returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.` So as I expect `Auth::check()` returns either TRUE or FALSE and **never** NULL it will never do what you want

Comment: @RiggsFollly It's just example. Another example --> 'string' == 'qwerty' ?? return false

Comment: @RiggsFolly You gave me an interesting idea!
What about return Auth:: check ?? "some text".
Just put the operator at the beginning?

Comment: The core of the issue is that `??` is *not* a ternary. It's (as mentioned already) a null coalescing operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the importance of NULL in this whole thing. the `??` is afterall called the **Null coalescing operator**

Examples

```
var_dump( true ?? "<h1>Log in please</h1>" ); 
var_dump( false ?? "<h1>Log in please</h1>" );  
var_dump( NULL ?? "<h1>Log in please</h1>" );
```

RESULT

```
bool(true)      <- operand1

bool(false)     <- operand1

string(22) "<h1>Log in please</h1>"     <- operand2
```

So ONLY when operand 1 in actually and specifically `NULL` will it return operand 2

Comment: Thank you guys, you are the best! Thanks for the explanation, and yes, I didn't know what ?? works only with NULL

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

```
Auth::check() ?: print "<h1>Log in please</h1>";
```

If `Auth::check()` is `true`, then this doesn't do anything, but if it's `false` it will print out the text.

Comment: Note that like echo, print is not a function, and does not have parentheses around its arguments. See this recent question for an example where this fact matters: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66452331/157957

Comment: Thank you guys, you are the best! Thanks for the explanation, and yes, I didn't know what ?? works only with NULL

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

- Firstly, `echo` cannot be used as an expression. However, `print` can, and otherwise does the same thing.
- Secondly, `??` checks it's left hand side for null, but you probably want to check for false, so need `?:`

So you could write this:

```
Auth::check() ?: print "<h1>Log in please</h1>";
```

Another way is to use a low-precedence `or`:

```
Auth::check() or print "<h1>Log in please</h1>";
```

Or of course you can just use an if statement:

```
if ( ! Auth::check() ) print "<h1>Log in please</h1>";
```

In which case you can use echo instead of print:

```
if ( ! Auth::check() ) echo "<h1>Log in please</h1>";
```

Comment: Thank you guys, you are the best! Thanks for the explanation, and yes, I didn't know what ?? works only with NULL